# if want the items to be leveled horitzontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

the problem is that i have to use display:inline-block , and the grey colored items in the pics should be leveled or inline horizontally above 1060px
see code
http://jsfiddle.net/wh6m8g5d/
**CSS**

```
.para {
  padding: 0 36px 24px 36px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}



.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 24px 0 2px;
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 43%;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  margin: 0px 36px 0px 0px;
}
  
ul{
    background-color:red;
    max-width:1026px
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p></span>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Serie A, LaLiga, Ligue1 und die UEFA Women´s Champions League live</p></span>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Der beste Kampfsport mit Boxen und UFC</p></span>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Weiterer internationalen Sport wie Handball, Motorsport, Tennis, WWE, Radsport & mehr</p></span>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Eine große Auswahl an Dokus und Shows aus der Welt des Sports</p></span>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Die UEFA Champions League inklusive Konferenz live – garantiert bis 2024</p></span>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Der beste US-Sport mit NFL, NBA, NCAA und MLB</p></span>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Die besten Darts Events mit Elmar Paulke nur auf DAZN</p></span>
    <span class="item"><p class="para">Zugang zu den Sendern Eurosport 1+2, Red Bull TV und Sportdigital TV</p></span>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQCOG.png)

i tried different things but couldn't get the results

Comment: what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want the grey items to be in line horizontally

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

in .para you set background-color 2 times, one is pink and  one is lightgray. Please remove the background-color: pink;

```
background-color: pink
padding: 0 36px 24px 36px;
background-color: lightgray
```

you can use

```
display: inline;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but what i want is the text to be  horizontally leveled, and that too using display inline block

Comment: please see as i have updated the description